# How out of fourier line calculate below sums?

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis

I put it down there (fourier line) since www page does not work.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC4Bn.png

.....
[image: fourier]

3 sums to calculate:
[image: 3sums]

Comment: hint : look at the Fourier series representation of $f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-m)$

Comment: ? I do not understand what do with this?

Comment: you had a course on Fourier series but you never eard about $\delta(x)$ and the periodized version $\sum_m \delta(x-m)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

For $(1)$, put $x=\pi$ in the Fourier expression and use the result that $\cos n\pi = (-1)^n$. And multiply both sides by $(-1)$.

For $(2)$, put $x=0$ in the Fourier expression.

Comment: @monday25 What is $PI^2$? I don't get that.

Comment: is fo 1) ok result $$ 7*π^2/6$$   and for 2) $$3*π^2 *0,5$$      ?